# My app is crashing when I use proguard obfuscation (Android Jack compiler)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard, obfuscation

I've been using JACK in my android application with android studio 2.0 and the latest gradle available, when I want to obfuscate the code using proguard I end whit a crash, but if I put -dontobfuscate in my proguard file the app works fine, How can I obfuscate my code when using JACK?

build.gradle (app module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.personal.project"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-jack-test.txt'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Proguard file:

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose


# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see      http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML    attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see     http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**

# Understand the @Keep support annotation.
-keep class android.support.annotation.Keep

-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class * {*;}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <init>(...);
}
```

Please note that if i use -dontobfuscate my app works perfectly

LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.my.personal.project, PID: 19382
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.personal.project/com.my.personal.project.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.af.o(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.a.setContentView(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.my.personal.project.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.af.o(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.a.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at com.my.personal.project.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.af.o(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.a.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at com.my.personal.project.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                   at android.support.design.internal.c.b(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.af.o(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.a.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at com.my.personal.project.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                   at android.support.design.internal.c.b(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.af.o(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.a.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at com.my.personal.project.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                   at android.support.design.internal.c.b(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.af.o(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.a.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at com.my.personal.project.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class android.support.v7.widget.r because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'android.support.v7.widget.r' appears in /data/app/com.my.personal.project-2/base.apk)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.bw.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                at and
```

Comment: Obfuscation always tests your patience and concepts of the language/framework. The only solution is to DEBUG.

Comment: When enabling the Jack toolchain, a built-in obfuscator/shrinker is used instead of ProGuard.

Comment: @T.Neidhart But if I extract the .class files and I open it with IntelliJ idea, the code isn't obfuscated at all I can even see the variables names... I may have to do something with Jack to activate the obfuscator, but I don't know it, acording to this comment "If the Jack toolchain is enabled, ProGuard is not executed at all. The specified proguard rules are evaluated and applied by the toolchain itself." The Jack toolchain uses the proguard rules specified in the proguard file, but in my case the app only work if I use "-dontobfuscate" flag... Any clue?

Comment: The internal obfuscator of the Jack toolchain may have bugs. Did you try to disable Jack and see if it works when obfuscating with ProGuard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix the problem adding this line in my proguard file

```
-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```

Comment: yeah, you cannot switch to jack and jill until about api 121 due to a previous Samsung effingup